# WAR deployed does not contain class

Tags: eclipse, jakarta-ee, war

### Problem

I am having this issue in one of my project, the WAR generated in eclipse when i do a **Run on server**, does not contains any .class.

- It does create the folders for the packages under WEB-INF\classes\ but no class are inside.

### What i tried

- I tried to create the WAR with maven and the resulting war does contains the class.
- I tried to create the WAR with eclipse manually via export > WAR and the resulting war does contains the class.
- I checked the WAR deployed on the JBoss server and it does not contains the classes in the WAR file.
- I tried to create the same project separately and it does work for the other project but not in the original one.

### Question

Why when i run the project integrated with JBoss server it deploy a WAR that does not include the .class files ? while when i create the WAR via maven or using the export option of eclipse it does include all the .class in the WAR file ?

Comment: _"Anyone had this issue before or something similar ?"_ is not a meaningful question here. Update your post with a **specific and answerable question** about your problem. See [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for more information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a eclipse version 03-2019 and switch to 09-2019, it solved the issue. From different forum i have seen that the issue is commonly due to 2 plugins trying to deploy the class on the server at same time and failing, mostly coming from JBOSS TOOLS. Maybe newer version of eclipse have solved this type of issue. I tried many workaround and only installing newer version without changing anything in the configuration makes it work.

As well update all the the plugin you have such as m2, jboss and others.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem happen to me for one of my Eclipse Dynamic Web projects.  Two projects work fine, but a third project produced a WAR file that did not contain a "files" directory entry in the WAR file that the other two projects WAR file contained.  It only contained the directory entries: META-INF and WEB-INF.  If you don't have the "files" directory entry then you don't have "WEB-INF/classes" that "fra" was mentioning.

I compared the various ".settings" files in the project that didn't work to the ones that did work. I saw a couple of small differences.  I made changes to the ".settings" files in the project that didn't work to match the ".settings" files in the projects that worked.  After I did that, I cleaned the project and exported a new WAR file and it now contained that missing "files" directory entry that I mentioned earlier.

The .setting files that I made changes in were "org.eclipse.wst.project.facet.core.xml", ".jsdtscope" and "org.eclipse.wst.common.component". In the first two settings files I had to modify a couple of "path" parameters.  The third setting files  had an old runtime name and reference different version of "installed facet".

In my case, I discovered the problem when I added that bad Dynamic Web project to an Eclipse TomCat server that I had configured. You can add that project to an Eclipse TomCat server, but you will get an error if you try to Debug or Start that server.  I don't have any explanation of why that one project was different from the others.

By the way, I using the 2023-09 version of eclipse.